# I delete cookies file in chrome but i'm still logged in after I restart Chrome

Tags: authentication, web-browser, cookies, chrome

I'm using linux and google chrome as browser. I know that cookeis are stored at /home/my_name/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies.

I deleted this file but it seems like when I restart Chrome and try to browse for example facebook, website logs me in. So I got little confused why do websites still authenticating me even if I don't have cookies file.
So my question is this. Is stealing Cookie file enough for someone to log in into any website that I was logged in? Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Firefox allows you to delete specific cookies. When I delete all Facebook cookies in FF, I'm logged out. So are you sure you're really deleting the cookies? Did you restart your browser?

Comment: Was Chrome closed when you deleted this file directly?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1002762/i-delete-cookies-file-in-chrome-but-im-still-logged-in-after-i-restart-chrome and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806199/i-delete-cookies-file-in-chrome-but-im-still-logged-in-after-i-restart-chrome

Answer (score 1):

## Local storage?

In modern browsers Facebook also uses "Local Storage" (although I don't know if for login), which is different from plain old cookies. ([Check using the `F12` key.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404813/how-to-view-or-edit-localstorage))

Comment: you can check it also in chrome://appcache-internals

Comment: I don't think Local Storage would be used for storing user credentials since any data stored in it could be easily accessible by javascript unlike http-only flagged cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Google keeps the passwords on their servers (aka cloud) and not local to your system. You can check your holdings by going to https://passwords.google.com/. Accordingly, your local store removal did not remove the entries.

This feature allows them to provide you their password management service across all your devices as long as you are logged in on a Chrome browser. Similarly, your web history is tracked and available from their cloud across devices as well.